# symfony2 Image not uploaded to server side

Tags: symfony, image-uploading, sonata-admin

I'm currently using symfony2+sonata admin bundle to upload image to the server. But what it success in local machine, it failed in server, the file is not uploaded on to the server. Anyone please help!

//image.php

```
class Image
{
/**
 * @var integer
 */
public $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
public $name;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
public $ord;

/**
 * @var \Ibase\StoreBundle\Entity\Product
 */
private $Product;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
public $path;

/**
 * Set id
 *
 * @param integer $id
 * @return Image
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Image
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set ord
 *
 * @param integer $ord
 * @return Image
 */
public function setOrd($ord)
{
    $this->ord = $ord;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get ord
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getOrd()
{
    return $this->ord;
}

/**
 * Set Product
 *
 * @param \Ibase\StoreBundle\Entity\Product $product
 * @return Image
 */
public function setProduct(\Ibase\StoreBundle\Entity\Product $product = null)
{
    $this->Product = $product;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get Product
 *
 * @return \Ibase\StoreBundle\Entity\Product 
 */
public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->Product;
}

//const SERVER_PATH_TO_IMAGE_FOLDER ='';

/**
 * Unmapped property to handle file uploads
 */
private $file;

/**
 * Sets file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}

/**
 * Get file.
 *
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

/**
 * Manages the copying of the file to the relevant place on the server
 */
public function upload()
{
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->getFile()) {
        return;
    }

    // we use the original file name here but you should
    // sanitize it at least to avoid any security issues

    // move takes the target directory and target filename as params
    $this->getFile()->move(
        $this->getUploadRootDir(),
        $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName()
    );

    // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
    $this->path = $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();

    // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
    $this->setFile(null);
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded
    // documents should be saved
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn’t screw up
    // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    return '/uploads';
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? 'null'
        : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * Lifecycle callback to upload the file to the server
 */
public function lifecycleFileUpload() {
    $this->upload();
}

/**
 * Updates the hash value to force the preUpdate and postUpdate events to fire
 */
public function refreshUpdated() {
//$this->setUpdated(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
}

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $updated;

/**
 * Set updated
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updated
 * @return Image
 */
public function setUpdated($updated)
{
    $this->updated = $updated;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updated
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getUpdated()
{
    return $this->updated;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getName() ? $this->getName() : "";
}
```

//imageAdmin.php (sonata)

```
class ImageAdmin extends Admin {

 protected $parentAssociationMapping = 'product';

 protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{

    $formMapper
      ->add('file', 'file', array('required' => false))
      ->add('name')
      ->add('Product', 'sonata_type_model', array('attr'=>array("hidden" => true)), array());  
 }


public function prePersist($image) {
    $this->manageFileUpload($image);
}

public function preUpdate($image) {
    $this->manageFileUpload($image);
}

private function manageFileUpload($image) {
    if ($image->getFile()) {
        $image->refreshUpdated();
    }
}

 /**
 * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper $showMapper
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
     $showMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('images')
        ->add('name');
}

/**
 * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper $listMapper
 * @return void
 */
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('images','images', array('required'=>false, 
            'template' => 'IbaseStoreBundle:Admin:list_images.html.twig'))
        ->add('name')
        ->add('product')
    ;
}
```

Sorry, I know it is a bit long, but there was't any error pop out, the file is just not went up to the server folder "uploads".

Comment: **The log shows:** [2014-09-22 02:27:46] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /th1s_1s_a_4o4.html"" at /home/ibase258/public_html/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1889 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for \"GET /th1s_1s_a_4o4.html\" at /home/ibase258/public_html/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1889, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException:  at /home/ibase258/public_html/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1003)"} []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally know what's wrong. I got two methods with different return:

```
protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
// the absolute directory path where uploaded
// documents should be saved
return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
// get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn’t screw up
// when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
return '/uploads';
}
```

But in my server side, the location of uploads dir is different from my local host. The image was uploaded, but in other place.

Answer (score 2):

Your system has no file create permission and can't create **uploads** directory.

You may try with this:

```
protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn’t screw up
    // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    $directory = '/uploads';
    if(!file_exists($directory)) {
        mkdir("/uploads", 0777);
      }

    return '/uploads';
}
```

Comment: Thx @hizbul25, but can you tell more specifically? Where to create permission? I am new to symfony2, thanks

Comment: Hi, thx for your reply @hizbul25, I have tried that, but it shows permission denied for mkdir(), and the 'uploads' folder is update public_html folder, I think I should not chmod of that? right? what do you think?

Comment: chmod -R 0777 projectfile

Comment: Thx @hizbul25 but unlucky is the server I'm using has no console connect, I have tried chmod in local and upload the folder. still 'mkdir(): Permission denied'.